# What is wrong with this DB Diagram?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this database diagram?

[image: DB Diagram]

Comment: Is `Dimension 4` need to have `PK` as `id_d4` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as stated on the Help Center > Asking page, "questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." It's okay to ask for help, it's not okay to ask others to do your work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946482/what-is-wrong-the-query -- homework??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fact table should contain foreign keys to the dimensions. I see only primary keys

Comment: That's what underlining can be taken to mean, but I'm getting very unsure as to whether that's what it might mean here.

Comment: It does state PK for every id_ though. So I guess we can assume we're talking Primary Keys here?

Comment: There are already foreign keys!